# How to set the label background color

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

I need to show label background color which is attached in following code. It's multiline label.

Here is code snippet.

```
self._coverTittle =[[FontLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 650, 400, 200) fontName:@"futurlig-webfont" pointSize:48.0f];

self._coverTittle.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green: 0 blue:0 alpha:0.4]; 
_coverTittle.numberOfLines = 5;
_coverTittle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

self._coverTittle.tag=5;
[self._coverTittle sizeToFit];
```

Comment: What do you mean by "_show_ label background color"?

Answer (score 0):

what you did should work: .backgroundColor.
If you want textcolor, you should .textColor.
But your question is a bit unclear, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
 self._coverTittle.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green: 0 blue:0 alpha:0.4];
```

You need to pass some value if Red, Green and Blue part if you want to set background color of your label.
Following link contains full document on the same- http://chris-software.com/index.php/tag/rgb-colors/

Comment: i m showing text  in lable dynamically  using number of lines.. i  want to show the background of the  text as per the text alignment. now i m showing the background  od the lable as per the frame size.

Comment: I have multiline lable which has dynamic text. so i need to show the background color for each line. if i set  self._coverTittle.backgroundColor   background is there but  it  showing the label frame size.it should be show the background as number of line.

Comment: @SubratTripathy means for a single label you want several color depending on line..if it is so then you can refer-https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel